# Controllable system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, fluid-dynamics

Let (A, B) is controllable and that rank B = n  , we want to show that the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue of A is at most n. Any help

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Recall that the controllability of the system $(A,B)$, where $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$, is equivalent to the Kalman criterion:

$$\text{rank} \left( \left[B |  AB | \dots | A^{n-1}B  \right] \right) = n$$